# How to add data into Firestore Swift by tapping on a cell

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have more restaurants , each have diferent food.[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJon.png)
This is how im retrieving data from the Firestore. In the previous controller I have a list of restaurants, each contains a list food.

```
struct Food {
    
    var photoKeyRestaurant: String
    var foodName: String
    var foodDescription: String
    var restaurantName: String
    var priceFood: Int
    
}

class RestaurantViewController: UIViewController {
    
   
    var restaurantName: String!
    var food: [Food] = []
  
    
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()

        return table
    }()

func getDatabaseRecords() {
        
       
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
           //  Empty the array
          food = []
            
        db.collection("RestaurantViewController").whereField("restaurantName", isEqualTo: restaurantName).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let newEntry = Food(photoKeyRestaurant: data["photoKeyRestaurant"] as! String, foodName: data["foodName"] as! String, foodDescription: data["foodDescription"] as! String, restaurantName: data["restaurantName"] as! String , priceFood: data["priceLabel"] as! Int
                        )
                        
                            
                            
                            
                        self.food.append(newEntry)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 //  self.datas = self.filteredData
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I add  the data of the selected cell by pressing on + to Firestore in this function ?
I'vrea create a protocol in my FoodTableViewCell , and I've called it in the RestaurantViewController.

```
 func diddTapButtonCell(_ cell: FoodTableViewCell) {
    
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("cart").addDocument.(data: foodName) { (err) in
            
        }
```

Edited: Added Table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food.count
      
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        let mancare = food[indexPath.row]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(mancare.photoKeyRestaurant)
        cell.foodImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = mancare.foodDescription
        cell.foodNameLabel.text = mancare.foodName
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(mancare.priceFood) lei"
        //Fac ca imaginea sa fie cerc  - start
        
        cell.foodImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.foodImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.foodImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.foodImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.foodImage.frame.height/2
        cell.foodImage.clipsToBounds = true
     
        //Fac ca imaginea sa fie cerc  - finish
        return cell
    }
```

This is my tableview cell code

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func diddTapButtonCell (_ cell: FoodTableViewCell)
}
class FoodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
   
    @IBOutlet weak var foodImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var foodNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func addToCart(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.diddTapButtonCell(self)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the code for your UITableView.

Comment: @Todd check it out

Comment: is diddTapButtonCell added as a target when you press the + button? I don't see 'objc' or 'IBAction' if connected through storyboard/interface builder. Also, If you are able to press anywhere on the cell I would instead implement the didSelectRowAt UITableViewDelegate method beneath cellForRowAt

Comment: @landnbloc I edited the question. Look into the TableView Cell

Comment: turn didTapButtonCell into a closure "var didTapButton : (()->())?" and then give it a value in your tableview's cellForAt function "cell.didTapButton = { //handle cell manipulation directly from here       } and make sure to add didTapButton?() to addToCart. This should work

Comment: @landnbloc you're missing my problem. My problem is that I don't know how to add the data into Firestore when im tapping

Comment: oh ok, the answer below will add data to the database if no document with that name exists and merge/update if it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231134/discussion-between-beuca-alexandru-and-landnbloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data
And here is an example from one of my projects for adding data to firestore.

```
 func updateDocument(rootCollection : String, doc: String, newValueDict: [String : Any], completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void = {_ in }) {
                
                 let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection(rootCollection).document(doc).setData(newValueDict, merge: true){ err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                        completion(false)
                        
                    }else{
                        
                        completion(true)
                      
                       
                    }
                }
                 
             }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing these with me, in newValueDict, how can I pass my values from the current cell ?

Comment: you actually do not want to pass the data from the cell because cells are reused and so not reliable to have the correct data as the tableview scrolls. This is why the "cell.didTapButton = { self?.updateDocument(newDataDict: ["foodDesc": mancare.foodDescription]) }" is as good idea. That way you can add data straight from you data source